# parse a complex json object

Tags: python, json, pandas, export-to-csv, json-deserialization

I created this json object from a yaml file. I tried to serialize it but i am getting errors.

```
{'info': {'city': 'Southampton',
  'dates': [datetime.date(2005, 6, 13)],
  'gender': 'male',
  'match_type': 'T20',
  'outcome': {'by': {'runs': 100}, 'winner': 'England'},
  'overs': 20,
  'player_of_match': ['KP Pietersen'],
  'teams': ['England', 'Australia'],
  'toss': {'decision': 'bat', 'winner': 'England'},
  'umpires': ['NJ Llong', 'JW Lloyds'],
  'venue': 'The Rose Bowl'},
 'innings': [{'1st innings': {'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
       'bowler': 'B Lee',
       'non_striker': 'GO Jones',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}},
       {'19.6': {'batsman': 'PD Collingwood',
       'bowler': 'GD McGrath',
       'non_striker': 'J Lewis',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0},
       'wicket': {'fielders': ['RT Ponting'],
        'kind': 'caught',
        'player_out': 'PD Collingwood'}}}],
    'team': 'England'}},
    {'2nd innings': {'deliveries': [{'0.1': {'batsman': 'AC Gilchrist',
       'bowler': 'D Gough',
       'non_striker': 'ML Hayden',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}},
     {'14.3': {'batsman': 'GD McGrath',
       'bowler': 'SJ Harmison',
       'non_striker': 'MS Kasprowicz',
       'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0},
       'wicket': {'kind': 'bowled', 'player_out': 'GD McGrath'}}}],
    'team': 'Australia'}}]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to convert this json object into a row in csv file.

**Code that i am trying to run:**

```
df=pandas.read_json(cric_match_json) # reading json object as pandas dataframe
df.to_csv()
```

**Error**

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: Show the code you're using and the complete error message you get when you use it.

Comment: You should mention the error you are getting along with the code that raises the exception. Right now what we have is just the JSON string with no information of what you want and why you get the error. Please edit the question with necessary information

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) method:

```
In [76]: d = {'info': {'city': 'Southampton',
    ...:   'dates': [datetime.date(2005, 6, 13)],
    ...:   'gender': 'male',
    ...:   'match_type': 'T20',
    ...:   'outcome': {'by': {'runs': 100}, 'winner': 'England'},
    ...:   'overs': 20,
    ...:   'player_of_match': ['KP Pietersen'],
    ...:   'teams': ['England', 'Australia'],
    ...:   'toss': {'decision': 'bat', 'winner': 'England'},
    ...:   'umpires': ['NJ Llong', 'JW Lloyds'],
    ...:   'venue': 'The Rose Bowl'},
    ...:  'innings': [{'1st innings': {'deliveries': [{0.1: {'batsman': 'ME Trescothick',
    ...:        'bowler': 'B Lee',
    ...:        'non_striker': 'GO Jones',
    ...:        'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}},
    ...:        {'19.6': {'batsman': 'PD Collingwood',
    ...:        'bowler': 'GD McGrath',
    ...:        'non_striker': 'J Lewis',
    ...:        'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0},
    ...:        'wicket': {'fielders': ['RT Ponting'],
    ...:         'kind': 'caught',
    ...:         'player_out': 'PD Collingwood'}}}],
    ...:     'team': 'England'}},
    ...:     {'2nd innings': {'deliveries': [{'0.1': {'batsman': 'AC Gilchrist',
    ...:        'bowler': 'D Gough',
    ...:        'non_striker': 'ML Hayden',
    ...:        'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0}}},
    ...:      {'14.3': {'batsman': 'GD McGrath',
    ...:        'bowler': 'SJ Harmison',
    ...:        'non_striker': 'MS Kasprowicz',
    ...:        'runs': {'batsman': 0, 'extras': 0, 'total': 0},
    ...:        'wicket': {'kind': 'bowled', 'player_out': 'GD McGrath'}}}],
    ...:     'team': 'Australia'}}]}

In [77]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(d)
Out[77]:
     info.city    info.dates info.gender info.match_type  info.outcome.by.runs info.outcome.winner  info.overs  \
0  Southampton  [2005-06-13]        male             T20                   100             England          20

  info.player_of_match            info.teams info.toss.decision info.toss.winner           info.umpires  \
0       [KP Pietersen]  [England, Australia]                bat          England  [NJ Llong, JW Lloyds]

      info.venue                   innings
0  The Rose Bowl  [{'1st innings': {'de...
```

Comment: That is great but how can i expand innings. There is so much data in there.